# How to make a SConscript in Scons aware of a header location?

Tags: python, c++, scons, godot

I'm trying to add a module to a game project based on [Godot](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/custom_modules_in_cpp.html). I wish to add unit tests using [doctest](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest). For simplicity, I'm going to use the example good given in the [link above](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/development/cpp/custom_modules_in_cpp.html). So I've created this simple file structure:

```
summator/
    include/
        summator.h
    src/ 
        summator.cpp
    tests/
        doctest.h
        summator_tests.cpp
        SCsub
    config.py
    register_types.h
    register_types.cpp
    SConstruct/SCsub
```

The last four files are required by Godot. Here's the `SConstruct`/`SCsub` (the second file name is needed by Godot, I used an SConstruct file to test in isolation):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# import the environment provided by Godot
Import( 'env' )
# when tested in isolation, replace with following line
# env = Environment()

# add include directory to the search path 
env.Append( CPPPATH = [ '#include' ] ) # relative path

# add all cpp files so Scons can build the module
env.add_source_files( env.modules_sources, 'src/*.cpp' )
env.add_source_files( env.modules_sources, '*.cpp' )

# if tests are enabled, build them 
if env[ 'tests' ]:
    SConscript([ 'tests/SCsub' ])
```

Next, the SConscript in `summator/tests/` supposed to build the tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

Import( 'env' )

tests_env = env.Clone()

# build tests
tests = test_env.Program( 'runTest', Glob( '*.cpp' )
```

When I try running this, I get an error that the header 'summator.h' can't be found:

```
[ 99%] Compiling ==> modules/summator/tests/sumator_tests.cpp
modules/summator/tests/summator_tests.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'summator.h' file not found
#include "summator.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
scons: *** [modules/summator/tests/summator_tests.linuxbsd.tools.64.llvm.o] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
```

The way I understand scons environments, once I've added a path/file to it, all SConscript (that import the environment) can access it. What am I doing wrong? This feels like it should be trivial, but for some reason it won't work.

Here are the other source files for completeness:

```
// summator.h
#ifndef SUMMATOR_H
#define SUMMATOR_H

#include "core/reference.h"

class Summator : public Reference 
{
    GDCLASS( Summator, Reference );

    int count;

protected:
    static void _bind_methods();

public:
    void add( int p_value );
    void reset(); 
    int get_total() const;

    Summator();
};

#endif // SUMMATOR_H
```

```
// summator.cpp
#include "summator.h"

void Summator::add( int p_value )
{
    count += p_value;
}

void Summator::reset()
{
    count = 0;
}

int Summator::get_total() const 
{
    return count;
}

void Summator::_bind_methods()
{
    ClassDB::bind_method( D_METHOD( "add", "value" ), &Summator::add );
    ClassDB::bind_method( D_METHOD( "reset" ), &Summator::reset );
    ClassDB::bind_method( D_METHOD( "get_total" ), &Summator::get_total );
}

Summator::Summator()
{
    count = 0;
}
```

```
// summator_tests.cpp
#define DOCTEST_CONFIG_IMPLEMENT_WITH_MAIN
// #include "thirdparty/doctest/doctest.h"
#include "summator.h"
#include "doctest.h"

TEST_CASE( "testing the summator" )
{
    // class under test
    Summator* cut = new Summator();

    cut->add(10);
    CHECK( cut->get_total() == 10 )
    cut->add(10);
    CHECK( cut->get_total() == 20 )
    cut->add(10);
    CHECK( cut->get_total() == 30 )
    cut->reset();
    CHECK( cut->get_total() == 0 )

    // clean up 
    delete cut;
}
```

Comment: Does it work in isolation but not in a Godot build?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've found a fix!

Answer (score -2):

After some experimenting, I found a solution that works, check out the full code in my [Github repository](https://github.com/georgjz/godot-module-template-with-unit-testing).

**Additional Appeasement Edit**:

```py
Import( 'env' )

print( 'Factorial module' )

# add include files 
env.Prepend( CPPPATH = [ './include' ] )
# add all cpp files
env.add_source_files( env.modules_sources, 'src/*.cpp' )
env.add_source_files( env.modules_sources, '*.cpp' )

tests = env.Program( 'runTests', [ Glob( 'tests/*.cpp' ) ] )
```

As I said, it's a workaround, I basically build a separate program `tests` that includes the code for the unit tests.

Comment: Without following the link, it is impossible to get even an idea about the way you resolve the problem. Stack Overflow discourages such answers, which are referred to as **link -only answers**. Please, add at least some information about the solution into the answer post itself. See also [answer].